# Unity game crashes when build but not in editor

Tags: error-handling, crash, unity-game-engine, access-violation

I'm working on a game. I have 30 levels. I spawn a level and destroy the old level at the end of each level. level 0 till 20 works perfect but after that it crashes when it loads the next level. all the levels are in 1 gameobject array.

If I put level 21 in the first place of the array it still happens, I rebuild the levels, checked my code but I just cant find the problem.

the error is a Access Violation(0xc0000005).

link to my error logs:
[Error logs download](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0da4e8e028ecbca58cfe484b35f9341220170123160242/75a577)

I also tried alot of other things, reimporting the project, check all the project settings and shader settings, build in older version of Unity, build on other computer.

Some one please help me, because I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: When you put the level 21 in the first place, does it still happen after 20 or it happens as the first level is being loaded?

Comment: Possible solution: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/950569/game-runs-in-editor-crashes-on-startup-after-build.html

Comment: @Dagohan when I put level 21 in the first place so in array[0], it happens diriectly at that the begin, so when level 21 is being loaded. I rebuilded the level already. And I already tried that solution but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you try to set level 21's GameObject array to an empty array and try building that. Just to understand if the is with one of the GameObjects inside the level 21's array.

Comment: Check out your log files, maybe it will provide a clue : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html

Comment: @Dagohan I tried, it won't crahs when I do that.

Comment: @Absinthe I can't find a clue in it haha

Comment: @Timonvw Then it seems that one of the GameObject in that array is causing the error. You have to spot which one is the trouble causer. (Troublesome GO might be more than one by the way). Try adding few of them to level 21's GO list and take build to spot which one is the problematic one. Then we can investigate the details of that particular GameObject to see what creates the error.

Comment: @Dagohan thanks, I found wich gameobject is causing the problem. I have a platform with wall in the levels were it is crashing and when I at it to a level that didnt crash it crashes. But not I dont know why it is crashing because of that gameObject mmm. Atleast I'm one step closer.

Comment: @Dagohan I found the problem, one of the artist put a animator on the particly system of the wall. I removed the animator and now it works! :)

Comment: @Timonvw Happy to hear that you solved your issue :)